# Problems with function on Shell Script

Tags: bash, function, shell

Trying to test functions on ShellScript, but I keep receiving the answer: "Command not found"

```
# Trying to create functions that receives arguments e have returns
# The function will receive two values and say hwo is bigger

bigger () {
if [$1 -gt $2]
then
   return $1
else
   return $2
fi
}

echo "Size does matter!!!!"
echo " "
printf "Enter the first number: - "
read data1
echo " "
printf "Enter the second number: - "
read data2
echo " "
printf "The bigger number is: - "
bigger $data1 $data2
```

The result I get is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzRfX.png)

Comment: Pasting your code into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) would have shown you your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error and bash tries to interpret `[1` as a command.
Add spaces to fix this

Change

```
if [$1 -gt $2]
```

to

```
if [ "$1" -gt "$2" ]
```

Comment: Still no good. Looks like it doesn't seen that the word bigger is a function.

Comment: If your aim is to output to the screen the bigger number then you need to use echo instead of return. 

return $1 => echo $1

Comment: Now it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If it works, then you should approve the answer